# Validate card details on stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a functionality where I am storing users credit card details in the database. Here is my same code

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = "stripe_api_key"

# create token for generating customer id
token = 
    Stripe::Token.create(
      card: {
        number: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        exp_month: xx,
        exp_year: xxxx,
        cvc: "xxx"
      },
   )

# Create a Customer:
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  email: "paying.user@example.com",
  source: token.id,
)

user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id
user.save
```

But before storing this customer id I need to validate given card i.e whether given card is exits and it is not expired.

So I have few doubts

1. Is there any stripe api that can provide me given details.
2. What is minimum charge we can make within Stripe.
3. Is there any better way to achieve this functionality. (Ex. charge certain amount to user and then refund it immediately)

Thanks

Comment: One of the benefits of using Stripe is keeping credit card details off your server. This [reduces your PCI Compliance Burden](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance) (which is mandatory if you want to accept credit cards) and is the between a form you can easily fill out yourself (SAQ A) and the 40 page SAQ D which often requires hiring a PCI professional. Are you **absolutely sure** your app needs to store card details?

Comment: @HenryMarshall No didn't have to store the card details. I need to store the stripe customer id so that I can reuse it.

Comment: If the customer details hit your server at all, as they necessarily are if you are running `Stripe::Token.create` server side, you have to comply with the stricter PCI rules. You (probably) want to be doing the tokenization in the user's browser via [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) on the web or the SDK for mobile.